# Simultaneous Row Operations in Gaussian Elimination [GStrang P253 5.1.20]

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose you do two operations at once: $-lR_1 + R_2 \rightarrow R_2$ and $-kR_2 + R_1 \rightarrow R_1$, 
>   going from $\begin{bmatrix}
>     a & b \\
>     c & d \\
>     \end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix}
>     a - kc & b - kd \\
>     c - la & d - lb \\
>     \end{bmatrix}$. Then the $\det$ of the second matrix = $ad \color{blue}{- abl}  \color{green}{- cdk} + bckl - bc +\color{green}{cdk} + \color{blue}{ abl} - adkl = (ad - bc)(1 - kl)$.

My textbook hasn't canvassed the question of simultaneous row operations, which only emerged while doing the above question. Could someone please do so? I remember that the row operation of adding a multiple of one row to another doesn't change the $\det$, but it does for concurrent ones as above.  [Purplemath](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/systlin6.htm) summarises it as:

> Note that I did two row operations at once in that last step before switching the rows. As long as I'm not working with and working on the same row in the same step, this is okay. In this case, I was working with the first row and working on the second and third rows.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that if $kl = 1$, then the determinant of your new matrix is $0$.  If the determinant of your old matrix is not zero, then this means that your new matrix is not row equivalent to your old matrix.

In general your "simultaneous row operations" replace each row of the matrix with a certain linear combination of the rows, but unlike for the actual row operations this process need not preserve the row space: it could make it smaller.  (One way to think about this is that you are proposing operations which are equivalent to left multiplication by a matrix which need not be invertible.) Because this key property of row operations can fail, it is not clear why you would want to do "simultaneous row operations".  I would suggest steering clear of them unless you know what you're doing.

I didn't track the link (and I don't have Strang's book), but there's a key sentence in your quote:

> As long as I'm not working with and working on the same row in the same step, this is okay.

Notice that your example violates this.  If you want to do "simultaneous row operations" on *disjoint sets of rows*, then no problem: it just amounts to doing one row operation and then the other, in either order (if you like, the corresponding elementary matrices commute).  This is not really a new concept as much as a remark that a certain abbreviated description of the row reduction process is justified.

Comment: Thank you again. Could you please elaborate on how simultaneous row operations could lessen the row space? I can't see it in the given matrices? Will you please to respond in your answer since comments are harder to read.

Comment: Do you understand why the row space of an invertible matrix is larger than the row space of a singular matrix?  You also might try starting with numerical values of $a,b,c,d$ with $ad-bc \neq 0$ and taking $k = l = 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your continued help. I remember: Any $n \text{ by } n$ invertible matrix must have $n$ pivots, which are more than any $n \text{ by } n$ singular matrix. Equivalently, the REF of a invertible matrix must have more rows than the REF of a singular matrix, which must contain $\ge 1 \mathbf{0}$ row. Is this what you meant? How would I connect this to my prior comment? Would you please respond in your answer?